# How to return information when returning a 500 Response

Tags: c#, .net, json, ajax

I want to return a 500 Exception with information from my backend to my frontend, but everytime I choose to do a `Response.StatusCode = 500` the code seems to return the 500 Standard Return page. Is there anyway to return my own data after I choose to tell the system it was a 500-error?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AccountInformation(OrganizationAccountInformationVM vm)
{
    var response = await _adminFacade.UpdateOrganizationAsync(organization);

    if (response.HasErrors)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return Json(new {Code = "500", Header = "Error", Message = "Wrong"});
    }
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return Json(new {Code = "400", Header = "Success", Message= "UpdatedSuccessful"}); 
}
```

This code will return "good" data if it has no errors, and "bad" data (a whole html-page) if the resposne HasErrors. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify to not replace error responses using the web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /> 
</system.webServer>
```

Take a look at [system webserver httperrors](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)

Comment: Thank you! This solves the problem for me! Is there anyway to do PassThrough for some error codes and Replace for some?

Comment: @user2687506 I believe if you set the status code but do not include any response the system will generate the error response.  I have not tried but reading the documentation indicates this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the default IIS error page, but instead show your own, you need to set the [`TrySkipIisCustomErrors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` on the response:

```
    public async Task AccountInformation(OrganizationAccountInformationVM vm)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        // your response with code 500
    }
```